# Multiple .Contains(...) on a list of custom class objects

Tags: c#

I would like to have multiple `.Contains(...)` methods on a list of Person objects, in particular a `.Contains([Person])` and `.Contains([int])` similar to how I can have `.Equals([Person])` and `.Equals([int])`. `.Contains([int])` is the problem because an int is an invalid argument for `.Contains(...)`.

Person class

```cs
private class Person
{
    private int number;
    private string name;

    public Person(int number, string name)
    {
        this.number = number;
        this.name = name;
    }

    public override bool Equals(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is int) return Equals((int) obj);
        if (obj is Person) return Equals((Person) obj);
        return false;
    }

    public bool Equals(int otherNumber)
    {
        return number == otherNumber;
    }

    public bool Equals(Person otherPerson)
    {
        if (number != otherPerson.number) return false;
        if (name != otherPerson.name) return false;
        return true;
    }
}
```

And this is what I am doing

```cs
Person a = new Person(1, "James");
Person b = new Person(1, "James");

List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(a);

a.Equals(b); // True
a.Equals(1); // True
persons.Contains(b); // True
persons.Contains(1); // Does not work
```

Comment: its because `.Contains` is a generic method...

Comment: @Nyerguds - he is overriding `Equals(object)` - it won't work because `List<T>` doesn't have a `Contains(object)` method only `Contains(T)` so there is no way to pass the `int` into his list `List<Person>` as Daniel already said `Contains` is a generic method

Comment: @Nyerguds you still wouldn't be able to pass an `int` to `List.Contains` if you overrode `Object.Equals(object)` on the `Person` class.

Comment: Yea, no, I noticed and removed the comment, but didn't see there were replies. Sorry about that.

Comment: This would be a lot simpler if `number` and `name` were exposed as public properties, btw... even if just readonly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use the [Enumerable.Any Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.linq.enumerable.any?view=netframework-4.8).

> Determines whether any element of a sequence exists or satisfies a condition.

You didn't say what `Contains(int)` should do, but I assume you're expecting it to return true if there is a `Person` whose `Equals(int)` returns true for the given `int`.

```csharp
Person a = new Person(1, "James");
Person b = new Person(1, "James");

List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(a);

a.Equals(b); // True
a.Equals(1); // True
persons.Contains(b); // True
persons.Any(p => p.Equals(1)); // True
```

If you want to call it through a method called `Contains(int)` you can use an [Extension Method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/programming-guide/classes-and-structs/extension-methods).

```csharp
public static class IEnumerableOfPersonExtensions
{
   public static bool Contains(this IEnumerable<Person> src, int number)
   {
      return src.Any(p => p.Equals(number));
   }
}

Person a = new Person(1, "James");
Person b = new Person(1, "James");

List<Person> persons = new List<Person>();
persons.Add(a);

a.Equals(b); // True
a.Equals(1); // True
persons.Contains(b); // True
persons.Contains(1); // True
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are mixing two types check with the single list. First you are checking person object `contains` with works, because the list is of `Person` type, where as you are trying to check `1` in `persons` list which is of type `int`. 
You need to change something like `persons.Select(x => x.PersonId).contains(1)`

Comment: That's what the Linq `Any` function does. No need to iterate the whole list.